# How to align the text to the left. in react-tooltip?

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, text-align, react-tooltip

I am using the react-tooltip to show the multiline tooltip,
but the problem is that the text is centered by default,
how do I align the text to left

```
<ReactTooltip/>
<img  
    data-effect="solid" 
    data-place="right" 
    data-multiline={true}
    data-tip="  Tooltip text line one <br/>
                Tooltip text line two <br/>
                Tooltip text longer than usual  line three<br/>
                Tooltip text line four <br/>
                Tooltip text line five <br/>
                Tooltip text last line" 
    style={{marginTop : "10px", marginLeft : "6px"}} 
    src={questionCircleImg} max-width="50" max-height="50" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give custom class to your tooltip using data-class attribute

```
<ReactTooltip/>
<img
alt=""
data-class="my-tooltip"
data-effect="solid" 
data-place="right" 
data-multiline={true}
data-tip="  Tooltip text line one <br/>
            Tooltip text line two <br/>
            Tooltip text longer than usual  line three<br/>
            Tooltip text line four <br/>
            Tooltip text line five <br/>
            Tooltip text last line" 
style={{marginTop : "10px", marginLeft : "6px"}} 
src={questionCircleImg} max-width="50" max-height="50" />
```

then in css overide tooltips style

```
.my-tooltip .multi-line {
   text-align: left !important;
}
```

here is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tooltip-example-3-11-6-forked-z2lz5?file=/src/styles.css:0-59

Comment: You can also set the class on the ReactTooltip element itself (using CSS Modules): `<ReactTooltip id="tooltip-id" place="bottom" effect="solid" className={styles.my-tooltip} />`